# Rename "example" directory in solr

Tags: magento, solr

I have installed **apache-solr-3.5.0** for my **magento** enterprise site. I have run the solr by using

`/etc/solr/apache-solr-3.5.0/example$ sudo java -jar start.jar` and it is perfectly working. So for the live site I have rename the "example" folder to another name say "project1" and I tried with

`/etc/solr/apache-solr-3.5.0/project1$ sudo java -jar start.jar` but I couldn't access the solar admin.

The execution stops at

```
2015-08-19 17:30:16.578:WARN::failed SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8983: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
2015-08-19 17:30:16.579:WARN::failed Server@309db6ff: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
2015-08-19 17:30:16.579:WARN::EXCEPTION 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.newServerSocket(SocketConnector.java:80)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.open(SocketConnector.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector.doStart(AbstractConnector.java:283)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector.doStart(SocketConnector.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:235)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

Is we have to rename the "example" directory in our production environment? If yes, How can I successfully rename the "example" directory?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: port is been used to start up is in use. This can be caused either by another application running on the port, or failed shutdown. Its not because of renaming example

Comment: check if you have a process already running on the 8983 port...if you are on linux Run: ps -aux | grep java.

Comment: I have checked that too. There is no process running in the same port

Comment: Is we need to rename the "example" folder for the production environment?

Comment: I have been using 3.3 version of it but dont remember of remaming the any example folder

Comment: okay, thanks for helping me

Comment: I solved this issue by killing all the process running in 8983 port. Thanks Abhijit Bashetti

Comment: Can I add this as an answer.. please accept it.

Comment: Sure. I am sorry, I have added myself, but removed now

Answer (score 0):

The error states that port is been used to start up is in use. This can be caused either by another application running on the port, or failed shutdown. Its not because of renaming example. There might be a process which is already running on the same port i.e 8983.

Kill the process running on the same port.